# Regional French in Balzac's “Une ténébreuse affaire”

Tags: vocabulaire, régionalismes

The paragraphs are from Balzac "Une ténébreuse affaire". I can't understand the words in italics, at least some of them.

" *M'n p'a* (mon papa) fait demander où faut mettre
*el brigadiais* qui ne va point *ben du tout ?*– De quoi se plaint-il ? dit Peyrade.– *Eu d'là tâte*, il s'a fiché *par tare ben drument* tout
de même. Pour un gindarme, qui *savions montar à
chevâlle*, c'est du guignon, mais il aura buté ! Il a un trou,
oh ! gros comme *cul' poing darrière la tâte*. Paraît *qu'il a
évu* la chance *ed'timber sur un méchant caillou*, pauvre
homme ! Il a beau *ette gindarme, i souffe* tout de même,
qué *çâ fû pitié".*

I just need the modern forms of words in italics. I don't need the whole text translated, in fact I don't even need it translated. I just can't figure out what those italicized words are.

Comment: What have you found in the dictionary or other research?

Comment: Almost nothing. I managed to understand the meaning of most of the words, except for the following:
1. "Eu d'là tâte". (I think it's something like "mal de tête" but I'm not sure)
2. "gros comme cul' poing darrière la
 tâte" (I think it's "gros comme un poing derrière la tête")
3".évu la chance ed'timber" ( I don't know what it means, I think "ed'timber" meant " de tomber", but I'm not sure).
For context, it's a conversation between two people who find an injured gendarme fallen off his horse. "tâte" is "tête", but what does "Eu d'là tâte" and the rest of the numbered words mean.

Comment: Il s'a fiché par terre bien drument (this is what I know)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> " M'n p'a (mon papa) fait demander où faut mettre el brigadiais qui ne va point ben du tout ?

Mon père demande où mettre le brigadier qui va pas bien du tout.

(brigadier : grade peu élevé dans la gendarmerie)

> – De quoi se plaint-il ? dit Peyrade.
> – Eu d'là tâte, il s'a fiché par tare ben drument tout de même.

- De quoi se plaint-il ?
- De la tête, il est tombé par terre bien durement (violement) quand même.

ici *Eu* est probablement une interjection.

> Pour un gindarme, qui savions montar à chevâlle, c'est du guignon, mais il aura buté !

Pour un gendarme qui sait monter à cheval, c'est pas de chance, mais il aura trébuché.

(C'est du guignon: C'est la guigne = C'est pas de chance, merci Jlliagre)

> Il a un trou, oh ! gros comme cul' poing darrière la tâte.

Il a un trou gros comme un coup de poing (??) derrière la tête.

> Paraît qu'il a évu la chance ed'timber sur un méchant caillou, pauvre homme !

Parait qu'il a eu [de] la chance de tomber sur un méchant caillou, pauvre homme.

> Il a beau ette gindarme, i souffe tout de même, qué çâ fû pitié".

Il a beau être gendarme, il souffre tout de même, ça fait pitié.

---

Je doute que Balzac avait en tête l'accent québécois, ça me semble plus un accent de nos provinces (Bourgogne ou Auvergne).

Comment: Thank you for your reply! It is very clear and explicit at the same time. Thanks for taking the time to help me out.

Comment: *C'est du guignon*: *C'est la guigne* = *C'est pas de chance*.

Comment: merci @jlliagre : c'est reporté.

Comment: Je ne suis pas sûr du tout que Balzac imite un dialecte régional en particulier honnêtement. Ce n'est clairement ni une langue d'oc ni du wallon. /evy/ pour eu est typique d'un triangle qui va de Paris à l'Alliers et au Jura (ALF 102), par example, alors que /ɛ̃/ pour "en" comme dans gendarme, l'absence de voyelle longue dans être > ette et la voyelle protéthique de "ed'timber" sont très picardes, Terre > /tar/ fait lorrain ou québécois et /a/ pour le suffixe -er est poitevin ou occitan (ce qui ne collerait pas du tout avec le reste)

Comment: Il y a aussi des trucs plus inexplicables, comme /mn/ pour "mon" devant consonne dans "m'n p'a" (c'est fréquent devant voyelle, pas devant consonne), "savions" à la troisième personne du singulier (du pluriel ça marcherait, pas du singulier), ou encore tomber > timber qui font penser à une imitation du langage populaire de la part d'un auteur qui n'en comprend pas les règles, et mélange allègrement des variantes régionales disparates.

Answer (score -1):

It is supposed to mimic the French Canadian accent. "montar à chevâlle" is "monter à cheval".

Comment: It's old regional French. Some words are easy to guess, some harder. Anyway, it's a start and I appreciate your response.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).